# ngx-intl-tel-input node module changing the styles

Tags: jquery, css, angular, css-selectors, angular8

I am using ngx-intl-tel-input module in my form to add user phone with country code. Below are the node modules I used to in my Angular 8 project.

```
ngx-intl-tel-input : ^14.1.0
bootstrap : ^4.4.1
ngx-bootstrap : ^5.6.1
```

As the node module needs the dependency of both bootstrap and ngx-bootstrap to work properly.

**ISSUE:**

- When I use the both bootstrap module, the ngx-intl-tel-input
  component works properly but the css styles for other pages affects
  causes the alignment issue.
- If I remove the bootstrap modules, the alignments of other page works
  well but in the ngx-intl-tel-input, when I select the country from
  the dropdown list, the list not closing.

Could someone help me resolve this issue or any workaround to close the list on selecting the country  from the list.

Comment: If you can create Stackblitz example, I could look into it.

Comment: Were you able to get this fixed?

Comment: I am facing same issue. @pasevin are you able to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bootstrap 4.4.1 dependency and add this piece of CSS to emulate the same behaviour:

```
.iti {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  .iti__flag-container .dropdown-menu.country-dropdown {
    display: none;
  }

  .iti__flag-container.open .dropdown-menu.country-dropdown {
    display: block;
    inset: 100% auto auto 0px;
    transform: translateY(0px);

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    min-width: 10rem;
    margin: .125rem 0 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: .25rem;
  }

  .tooltip {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1070;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: start;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-break: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    white-space: normal;
    line-break: auto;
    font-size: .875rem;

    & .arrow {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: .8rem;
      height: .4rem;

      &:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        border-color: transparent;
        border-style: solid;
      }
    }
    &.show {
      opacity: 0.9;
    }
  }

  .bs-tooltip-top {
    padding: .4rem 0;

    &.tooltip .arrow:before {
      top: 0;
      border-width: .4rem .4rem 0;
      border-top-color: #000;
    }

    & .arrow {
      bottom: 0;
    }
  }

  .tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: .25rem .5rem;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: .25rem;
  }
}
```